# Left and right double quotation mark is not showing in tailwind css

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-elements

In the below code while using tailwind css, I added the psuedo class before and added content-['\201C'] and similarly added the right quotation mark as well which is content-['\201D'] and I am using the live server extension and running this on edge but still I couldn't see the symbols

I tried changing the code and I added unicode character directly but I want to add this as a content psuedo class and first I thought it was a quotation mark issues but even after double checking I'm seeing this issue

```
 <figure class="my-12">
<blockquote class="bg-teal-600 dark:bg-black pl-14 pr-8 py-12 rounded-3xl relative">
                    <p class="text-2xl sm:text-3xl text-left mt-2 text-white dark:text-slate-400 before:content-['\201C'] before:font-serif before:absolute before:top-0 before:left-0 before:text-9xl before:text-white before:opacity-25 before:transform before:translate-x-2 before:translate-y-2 after:content-['\201D'] after:font-serif after:absolute after:-bottom-20 after:right-0 after:text-9xl after:text-white after:opacity-25 after:transform after:-translate-x-2 after:-translate-y-2">
                    
                        Acme
                        has always been there
                        for me. Their Explorer rocket arrived in a wooden crate as expected.
                        Life-long customer! A++ shopping experience.
                    </p>
                </blockquote>
                <figcaption class="italic text-xl sm:text-2xl text-right mt-2 text-slate-500 dark:text-slate-400">
                    &#8212;Wile E. Coyote, Genius
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
```